# Evolución anómala de la expresión "ser de cajón"

Tags: etimología, expresiones, significado, españa, dle

Partiendo de [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19152/12637) a otra pregunta me puse a buscar el significado y etimología de la expresión "ser de cajón algo", dado que para mí la expresión significa (así sin consultar) que algo es obvio, indudable. Una consulta a la RAE [confirmó mis sospechas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6eaAt2X), pero cuando fui a buscar el significado de la expresión, encontré artículos que hacían referencia a [otra explicación](http://www.fundacionlengua.com/es/cajon/art/207/) de la misma.

Así que me puse a buscar el significado de la expresión con el paso del tiempo. La primera ocurrencia aparece en el diccionario de la RAE de 1817:

> **SER DE CAJON**. f. Ser alguna cosa corriente y de estilo.

Dejado de lado el hecho de que me sorprende que una cosa pueda ser corriente y de estilo al mismo tiempo, fui siguiendo la evolución de la expresión, que se mantiene invariable hasta 1970:

> **ser de cajón una cosa**. fr. Ser corriente y de estilo.

para pasar de golpe y porrazo en la siguiente edición (1984) a significar:

> **ser de cajón una cosa**. fr. fig. y fam. Ser evidente, obvia, estar fuera de toda duda o discusión.

¿Cómo dio un cambio tan brusco la expresión, sin que convivieran ambas acepciones siquiera durante un tiempo? ¿Qué tiene que ver el significado anterior con el actual? ¿Se sigue utilizando el significado antiguo hoy día?

Comment: Qué curioso eso de "_corriente y de estilo_", desde luego no es común que algo sea a la vez corriente y con estilo. Supongo que se referiría a algo social y comúnmente aceptado como "con estilo". El cambio tampoco es poca cosa, ¿tal vez "_de estilo_" tenía otra acepción entonces? El cambio sería mucho menor si solo pasara de corriente a obvio.

Comment: @Nox una de las acepciones de "estilo" en 1817 era "uso y moda que hay y se guarda comunmente". Por tanto sería sinónimo de "ir a la moda". Así se explica mejor, dado que "ir a la moda" es "seguir la corriente". Aun así sigue existiendo el salto entre significados.

Comment: Yo creo que cuando dice "de estilo" quiere decir "lo que se lleva, lo aceptado, lo que es normal o natural ver", en lugar de "fuera de serie, elaborado, sofisticado o sobresaliente". Es decir, vestir estilo siglo XVII es "lo corriente"... en el siglo XVII. Por tanto, yo no veo necesariamente una contraposición ahí. Y el significado evoluciona de "es lo esperado, común y normal" a "obvio" porque lo común y normal es obvio. Aparte, puede que el origen esté en "la primera prenda que encuentro en el cajón" o similar, luego, algo normal, que se lleva.

Comment: Acerca del sentido de *ser algo de estilo* se la puede comprender con otro uso equivalente y común, *estilarse* 

_En los juegos entre amigos se estilaba zanjar nuestras diferencias y discusiones entre bromas en una reunión amable tras terminar los partidos_

Answer (score 1):

Dado que esta es una pregunta interesante, vamos por partes:

> ¿Cómo dio un cambio tan brusco la expresión, sin que convivieran ambas acepciones siquiera durante un tiempo?

Es poco probable que la acepción de una palabra cambie de manera tan radical de una edición del diccionario a la siguiente. La razón por la cual ocurre el cambio sería precisamente para aclarar la interpretación que algo "corriente" es opuesto a algo de "estilo", comparando las definiciones se nota que de una edición a la otra se procura dar más precisión y claridad:

- Las entradas anteriores sólo muestran "*f.*" y "*fr.*", aludiendo que es una frase, mientras que la siguiente entrada especifica "*fr. fig. y fam.*", esclareciendo que es una frase figurativa y familiar.
- Las últimas dos entradas aluden a "*una cosa*" en la frase a definir, resultando en un cambio de estilo que culmina con una sensación de desface entre la primera y última acepción.
- El estilo de la entrada también cambia para ser más explícito, de continuar con el mismo estilo, la definición solamente sería "*Ser evidente y obvia*". En cambio, la entrada intenta dejar fuera cualquier ambigüedad al incluir la aclaración "*estar fuera de toda duda o discusión*".

Es posible que aparecieran connotaciones tanto de "*corriente*" y "*estilo*" que causaran la confusión que se expresa en la pregunta. "*Corriente*" inicialmente sólo implicaba ser "*habitual*" o "*común*" para posteriormente expresar algo "*carente de clase*" (*[vulgar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c5Ns9tE%7Cc5O7ZCI)*), esa connotación se contrapone con "*estilo*" que implicaría lo opuesto, volviendo la definición paradójica.

"*Estilo*", por su parte, puede verse el uso que originalmente se le otorgaba al observar la definición de "*estilar*":

> **[De estilo.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Gs06BsB%7CGs0XLqT)**
>
> 1. intr. Usar, tener por costumbre, practicar. Se disfrazó según estilaban los romanos. U. t. c. tr. Acamparán como estilan hacerlo los indígenas.

Es decir, "*estilo*" en, este caso, sería equivalente de "*acostumbrar*".

La siguiente aclaración ("*estar fuera de toda duda o discusión*") apoya esta teoría, ya que, al agregarse, se evitaría un problema similar en caso de nuevas connotaciones afectaran las palabras usadas para definir la frase.

Por lo tanto, si se observa que las acepciones anteriores pueden verse como "*cosa habitual (común) y que se acostumbra (estila)*" se puede observar que no se encuentran tan lejos de "*[cosa] evidente, obvia*", dado que cosas que son habituales se dan por sentadas, se vuelven evidentes y obvias.

> ¿Qué tiene que ver el significado anterior con el actual?

Partiendo de la conclusión mostrada en la parte superior, el significado procuraría ser el mismo, el cambio es en la manera de presentarlo para evitar confusión y que la acepción sea "*evidente, obvia*".

> ¿Se sigue utilizando el significado antiguo hoy día?

De igual manera, si se consideran los dos puntos previos, el significado utilizado continuaría siendo igual por lo que se seguría utilizando.

---

Ahora bien, la frase "*ser de cajón*" se ha vuelto, irónicamente, en "*una frase de cajón*".

Las "*frases de cajón*" son aquellas que se repiten tanto que tienden a tornarse [trilladas](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/clich%C3%A9.1012024/) o [clichés](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9SlqXDz). El que sean tan comunes, corrientes, evidentes y obvias muestran la poca creatividad de la persona que las esgrime, al punto que hay individuos que las repiten como loros, sin saber su significado real (Cosa que no me agradaría hacer).

Estas connotaciones las encontré al validar la [respuesta a la que se refiere esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15838/whats-the-spanish-expression-for-boilerplate-code?noredirect=1&lq=1), incluyendo otros significados asociados con la frase.

---

Con relación a la respuesta vinculada, generalmente procuro realizar una investigación antes de responder para así cotejar lo que considero es adecuado contra usos documentados de una traducción, frase o impresión. Claro que existen sus excepciones, como la de [explicar una caricatura](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19064/understanding-a-cartoon/19065#19065), y en algunos no he incluído todos los vínculos de referencia como en [cómo decir "porque sí"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19083/how-to-say-because-in-spanish/19084#19084) y, en cierta medida, [cómo aplicar el concepto de inclusividad en Español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19044/c%C3%B3mo-se-podr%C3%ADa-aplicar-el-concepto-de-inclusividad-en-espa%C3%B1ol/19069#19069).

Yo considero más importante el dar una respuesta con un cierto nivel de "bibliografia electrónica" que el dar una respuesta rápida, por lo que generalmente no soy el primero en responder (Exceptuando [cómo traducir línea de trampas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19058/translating-trapline/19059#19059), [cómo decir "porque sí"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19083/how-to-say-because-in-spanish/19084#19084), entre otras). Esto también causa que mis respuestas se tarden más, por lo que me duele cuando pierdo mis borradores (como en [la respuesta referida](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15838/whats-the-spanish-expression-for-boilerplate-code?noredirect=1&lq=1)) y que no responda otras preguntas para las cuales no me siento calificado o no he encontrado suficiente evidencia que avale lo que tengo en mente.

En el caso en particular de "*boilerplate code*", la frase de "*código de cajón*" la he escuchado y visto al ejercer mi profesión. Al notar que [la respuesta aceptada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15838/whats-the-spanish-expression-for-boilerplate-code/15846#15846) difunde el uso de un término distinto que puede causar confusión al realizar traducciones decidí añadir la respuesta (Dado que yo no voto negativamente). Lo que menos deseo es que se propague un término erróneo, por lo que si alguien considera que la traducción no es adecuada, agradecería que me lo hiciera saber con un comentario sobre la [respuesta en cuestión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15838/whats-the-spanish-expression-for-boilerplate-code?noredirect=1&lq=1).